# Strange behavior with shiny and ggplotly axis labels

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, ggplotly

Sorry if this has been echoed elsewhere, I can't seem to find any info on this.

I found a strange bug when creating an interactive markdown document with RMarkdown, shiny, and plotly. Basically when I have a `selectInput` tab in the document which is then used to filter a data frame, the axis labels are incorrect but only for the `selected=` or the default first argument. Here's a MCVE

````
---
title: "MCVE"
author: "author"
date: "6/8/2020"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---
```{r iris, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
require(shiny)
require(plotly)
require(tidyverse)

inputPanel(
  selectInput("Species", label = "Species",
              choices = unique(as.character(iris$Species)), selected = "setosa"))

renderPlotly({
  iris %>%
    filter(Species == input$Species) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width)) +
      geom_point() -> g1

  ggplotly(g1)
})
```
````

Here is a screenshot where you can see the error: 
[image]

Note the tooltip displays the correct values for Sepal Length and Sepal Width, but the labels on the x- and y-axes are incorrect.

This problem does not exist for the other options in the `selectInput`, seen here for "versicolor". For both versicolor and virginica the tooltip values match the axes labels. 
[image]

Note that this problem persists even if you don't specify a `selected` value. Am I using something incorrectly or is this a bug?

````
```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

Random number generation:
 RNG:     Mersenne-Twister 
 Normal:  Inversion 
 Sample:  Rounding 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] plotly_4.9.2        viridis_0.5.1       viridisLite_0.3.0   ROCR_1.0-11         ncdf4_1.16.1        aws.s3_0.3.12      
 [7] googlesheets4_0.2.0 rnoaa_0.8.4         rvest_0.3.5         xml2_1.2.5          forcats_0.4.0       stringr_1.4.0      
[13] dplyr_0.8.3         purrr_0.3.3         readr_1.3.1         tidyr_1.0.2         tibble_2.1.3        ggplot2_3.3.0      
[19] tidyverse_1.3.0    
```
````

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this issue in `R 4.0` iin `mac` and `packageVersion('shiny')
[1] ‘1.4.0.2’
> packageVersion('plotly')
[1] ‘4.9.2.1’
> packageVersion('dplyr')
[1] ‘0.8.99.9003’`

Comment: The same is true for me. Maybe you have to update `plotly` to 4.9.2.1.

Comment: Solved! After reading these comments I updated to 4.9.2.1 and the problem is fixed. I saw this in the most recent package update:
[Fixes a ggplotly() bug in axis tick translation (#1725, #1721)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotly/news/news.html).